# in app purchase in iOS using parse and objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, ios8

I want to implement in app purchase in iOS using parse.com and objective-C.I've searched over the internet but nothing find helpful even I've not any way to start to try still. Please, help me to implement it. 
many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually don't like to answer as link only. Mainly due to link rot, but since this reference is from a blog I trust it wont be deleted anytime soon.

Parse is well documented and offers a lot of open resources, you should always check with them first to see if they have any documentation related to your issue at hand because chances are, they do:

http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/24/in-app-purchase/

Paraphrasing from the blog the chance link rot prevails:

> Let’s say you want to sell a product named “Pro” that gets rid of all the ads in the app:

```
// First, register a handler for the product
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"Pro" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
// Write business logic that should run once this product is purchased.
isPro = YES;
}];

// ... Later, when the user is purchasing the product:
[PFPurchase buyProduct:@"Pro" block:^(NSError *error) { ... }];
```

> Parse can host your digital downloads and deliver them securely. Using the data browser, you can upload the content files to the Product class on Parse. To download the file in the app:

```
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"Pro" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
[PFPurchase downloadAssetForTransaction:transaction completion:
        ^(NSString *filePath, NSError *error) { ... }];
}];

// ... Later, when the user is purchasing the product:
[PFPurchase buyProduct:@"Pro" block:^(NSError *error) { ... }];
```

Comment: +1 for your answer but I didn't understand where to start. I never did IAP for app this is my 1st time and it is with parse.com

Comment: Is it still not clear @AnkitNeoGHz ? Here is a more thorough walk through https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#iap/iOS

Comment: Sorry soulshined, I'm still in trouble.

Comment: Then it sounds like a separate question @AnkitNeoGHz . Once you have implemented the code per the Parse documentation and still can't figure it out, please post a separate question on the particular instance you got stuck at so future question seekers have the same opportunity to learn (they more than likely won't scroll through comments to find an answer). The specific question in this case was answered how to implement in-app purchases with parse, but a specific problem to _your_ project should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I will do but I've a question to you. With these two methods I can implement in-app-purchase (I'm only selling product not any download).

Comment: @AnkitNeoGHz if your not downloading anything to the device (say for $0.99 you can buy 1000 coins or just to remove ads) then the fist step should suffice. but sometimes you need to include things hosted out-of-app and don't want to sacrifice storage space, thats what the second step is for. Also, don't forget to pass app-store guidelines you have to include a "Restore Purchases" button.

Comment: +10 for your help soulshined.. many thanks for your help..now I'm going to take a try..